# SQL JOIN (nvarchar(Max), null)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use JOIN or WHERE Or whatever works to match values of ProductAttributeCombination.AttributeXml with ProductAttribute to get

```
p.Id, 
p.Sku, 
p.[Name], 
v1.[Name] AS Color, 
v2.[Name] AS Size, 
c1.StockQuantity
```

From

```
SELECT 
p.Id, 
p.Sku, 
p.[Name], 
v1.[Name] AS Color, 
v2.[Name] AS Size
-- , c1.StockQuantity
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping m1 ON m1.ProductId = p.Id 
INNER JOIN Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping m2 ON m2.ProductId = p.Id 
INNER JOIN ProductAttribute a1 ON a1.Id = m1.ProductAttributeId AND a1.[Name] = 'Color'
INNER JOIN ProductAttribute a2 ON a2.Id = m2.ProductAttributeId AND a2.[Name] = 'Size'
INNER JOIN ProductAttributeValue v1 ON v1.ProductAttributeMappingId = m1.Id
INNER JOIN ProductAttributeValue v2 ON v2.ProductAttributeMappingId = m2.Id
--  INNER JOIN ProductAttributeCombination c1 ON c1.ProductId = p.Id 
WHERE p.Deleted = '0'
```

But when I JOIN ProductAttributeCombination, it duplicate results.

ProductAttributeCombination contains ProductId Foreign Key.

Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping contains ProductId and ProductAttributeId Foreign Keys.

ProductAttributeValue contains Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping Foreign Key.

ProductAttributeCombination.AttributeXml is (nvarchar(Max), null)

And this is the ProductAttributeCombination table.

```
Id  ProductId   AttributesXml                                   
1169    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>112</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>115</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1170    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>112</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>116</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1171    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>112</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>117</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1172    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>113</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>115</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1173    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>113</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>116</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1174    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>113</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>117</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1175    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>114</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>115</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1176    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>114</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>116</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1177    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>114</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>117</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1145    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>102</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>104</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1146    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>102</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>105</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1147    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>102</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>106</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1148    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>103</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>104</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1149    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>103</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>105</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1150    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>103</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>106</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1160    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>108</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>104</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1161    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>108</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>105</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1162    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>108</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>106</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
```

This is the results of query I provide in the beginning without  c1.StockQuantity.

```
Id  Sku             Name            Color         Size
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK           S
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   RED             S
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE     S
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   pre             S
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK           M
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   RED             M
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE     M
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   pre             M
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK           L
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   RED             L
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE     L
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   pre             L
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     BLACK           S
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     RED             S
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     LIGHT BLACK     S
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     BLACK           M
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     RED             M
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     LIGHT BLACK     M
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     BLACK           L
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     RED             L
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     LIGHT BLACK     L
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   RED             S
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK           S
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE     S
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   RED             M
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK           M
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE     M
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   RED             L
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK           L
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE     L
```

Comment: Can you clarify what constitutes StockQuantity in the XML? Is it one of the the <Value> values? Is it the count of records matching the join criteria? Also, I think you need to better explain the join/match criteria? I'm guessing that <ProductAttribute ID="..."> is supposed to match some value from the ProductAttribute or ProductAttributeValue table, but it is not clear what the complete matching criteria is.

Comment: Having your XML stored as NVARCHAR may cause significant performance problems if the values are converted to XML on the fly in the join sources and conditions of your query. You would be much better off storing the XML as an XML type.

Comment: I suggest that you post a complete collection of table definitions and sample data to demonstrate the problem you are working. Adding this to your original post and posting a link to a fiddle (similar to the one I linked in my initial answer) would give us something concrete to work with, instead of guessing. Also, expand your desired results with your expected StockQuantity values for the given data, and how that is calculated from the data.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of the following will give you a starting point:

```
SELECT
    PAC.Id,
    PAC.ProductId,
    PAC.AttributesXml.value('(/Attributes/ProductAttribute[@ID="59"]/ProductAttributeValue/Value)[1]', 'int') AS Value
FROM ProductAttributeCombination PAC
```

```
SELECT
    PAC.Id,
    PAC.ProductId,
    PAC.AttributesXml.value('(/Attributes/ProductAttribute/ProductAttributeValue/Value)[1]', 'int') AS Value
FROM ProductAttributeCombination PAC
WHERE PAC.AttributesXml.value('(/Attributes/ProductAttribute/@ID)[1]', 'int') = 59
```

```
SELECT 
    PAC.Id,
    PAC.ProductId,
    N.Node.value('(ProductAttributeValue/Value)[1]', 'int') AS Value
FROM ProductAttributeCombination PAC
CROSS APPLY PAC.AttributesXml.nodes('/Attributes/ProductAttribute[@ID="59"]') N(Node)
```

The first is closest to what you started with, but also yields null values for the unmatched rows. The second moves the filter condition to a `WHERE` clause, but is likely suboptimal.  The third selects just those nodes that satisfy your  condition and then drills down further to extract the value.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/z3YuSL6H).

Comment: Thank you for the information. I get an "Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max).
" error message when I execute the first and second query.

Comment: Works in the fiddle. Did you get a clean copy?  Updating your original post with your desired results would also be useful in narrowing down the solution.  (I'll check back in a couple of hours.)

Comment: Thank you, and I edit my question to provide an exact situation for clarification.